# Binding process occurs before action is taken in JSF 2

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces with JSF 2.0, I have this layout:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="panelGroup" binding="#{bean.boundPg}" />
<p:commandButton value="Update" action="#{bean.updateMe}" update="panelGroup" />
```

in which, the bean is `SessionBean`. By using log4j to debug I found out that the binding process called `getBoundPg` before executing the action `updateMe`. So the view is always out-of-date.

Do you know why and how to reverse that order? Thanks!

------------- Edit ---------------

I'm making a web app for a quiz game.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="pgContents" binding="#{bean.boundContents}" />
<p:commandButton value="Prev page" action="#{bean.prevPage}" update="pgContents" /> 
<p:commandButton value="Next page" action="#{bean.nextPage}" update="pgContents" />
```

`pgContents` contains many `h:pannelGroup`s, each sub-group contains a label showing the content of a quiz, a `h:inputText` for the player to give their answer. Because of some reasons, I had to generate the children of `pgContents` programmatically.

The `Prev page` and `Next page` buttons will retrieve the prev/next group of quiz

Below is the bean (getters & setters are skipped)

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@SessionScoped
public class LessonHelper {

    private int currentPage;
    private HtmlPanelGroup boundContents;

    public void prevPage() {
        // decrease currentPage
        // fetch contents
        // add children for boundContents (label, inputText)
    }

    // nextPage() is similar
}
```

My problem is that, when I click the Prev/Next button, the getter `getBoundContents` is called first in binding process, and the `prevPage()/nextPage()` is called later, which cause the content always out-of-date.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is the natural way, as you can see in this wonderful tutorial by BalusC: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html

Tell me exactly what do you want to do, show what's inside that bean and a solution to your problem will be found!

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for your help but I haven't found any solution.

Comment: @hirikarate Are doing anything is those setter? If you wouldn't do anything, I don't see where the problem is... the binding is calling the setter and the component is bound, but then you call the method for previous navigation and add some children to the already bound component...

Comment: I want the prevPage()/nextPage() methods to run earlier than the binding process, so that I can update my content before it is rendered. Do you have any way to achieve that?

Comment: @hirikarate I don't really agree with you but if you do want that than call the `updateMe` method inside the `boundPg` method, before the binding... and delete the `action` attribute of commandButton

Comment: Hjx, I thought of that way before. But in `getBoundContents()`, I have no way to tell apart whether it is called by the binding process or something else, especially... no way to know whether I should call `prevPage()` or `nextPage()`. If you don't think it a good way, can you suggest me some way else?

Comment: @hirikarate Try using `immediate = true` commandButton attribute...see if it works!